# Setting up an if statement with window.location.origin in JS

Tags: javascript, location, hostname, pathname

I am looking to delete my navigation menu on the landing page of a site I am building. However, I can't figure out how to ONLY target that page. The way I do it with the other pages, is that I write (window.location.pathname.includes("/pathname")) when I want to target a specific page.

But if I want to target the origin ([www.hostname.com](http://www.hostname.com)) of the site,  I can't seem to do it without deleting the nav menu on all other pages since they all share the same hostname.

This is the function I am trying to execute:

```
function landingPage() {
  if (window.location.origin === "www.something.com") {
    document.querySelector(".main-navigation").remove("#primary-menu");
    document.querySelector(".site-branding").remove(".custom-logo");
  }
}
```

Comment: The [`remove()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove) doesn't accept any arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to target a specific page on a site, then you need to check `location.href` or `location.pathname` as you are doing for other pages.

The origin defines the entire site, not its homepage.

Answer (score 0):

```
function landingPage() {
  if (window.location.hostname === "www.something.com"  && window.location.pathname==="/") {
      /*Your Condition Comes here */
  }
}
```

window.location.hostname  will return the hostname of your website. You can compare the hostname and write the required condition you want to add.

to know more click [window location](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp)

Answer (score -1):

What if you combine `window.location.origin` with a `window.location.pathname` conditional?

`window.location.pathname` should return `"/"` if you are on the landing page and not a sub-page.

Comment: i managed executing the function by using (window.location.pathname === "/")